# Azure Worker role processing is very slow

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, parallel-processing, azure-worker-roles

I have a C# ETL process which run once in a week and it takes 6 hours to complete on-premises windows server.

Here is the C# class structure.

Source database: Firebird database files downloaded everytime on disk, takes 20 mins to download.

Destination: SQL Server (on-prem)

Load process steps are here.

1. Do something
2. Do something
3. Execute parallel

We have 5 firebird independent db files which work on 5 different tables so set the max degree of parallelism to 5.

```
Parallel.ForEach(destTables, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5}, (eachtable) =>
                {
                    var tableName = eachtable.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    lock (tableName)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(10000);
                        readTable.BulkLoad(tableName, srcConForMainFile, destConForSQL);
                        Thread.Sleep(10000);                        
                    }

                });
```

4. Do something
5. Complete the process

Now, I moved this process to Azure worker role.

Source database: Firebird database files downloaded on worker role disk (local storage=100GB set in .csdef file), taking 20-30 mins to download which is fine.

Destination db: Dedicated SQL Azure database of S3 Standard (100 DTUs) created in the same region where is worker role is created

I have setup a Large size worker role (4 cores, 7 GB RAM, High Net Bandwidth, 999 GB disk size) but the process took 20 hours to complete.

I also noticed that the CPU utilization has gone upto maximum 25% at some time and RAM used upto 2.5 or 3GB. That's it.

Is Parallel.ForEach working really in the worker role VM ?

How to verify Parallel execution is happening in worker role VM ?

Should we still increase the db to a higher pricing tier ?

Are there any other settings should be made to worker role VM so that the process runs much faster - 6hrs vs 20hrs ?

Comment: by default 2 instances must be running to stick to their SLA. did u try that  and see if it improved the performance.? also Parallel.Foreach  looks at number of cores on your server and other parameters and generally only kicks off number of threads it thinks it can handle, without knowing too much about what's in those threads. So, if you have a lot of non-CPU bound threads that can be kicked off at the same time without causing CPU over-utilization, default behaviour will not likely run them optimally.

Comment: This is likely not a programming issue and the question will likely be closed. That said: You haven't mentioned the hardware sku for your worker role instances. If it's A-series, you're using 1st-generation VMs, vs D-series. My guess is you're using A3 (4 core, 7GB).